# Prevent grouping of taskbar icons for an application

Tags: winapi, windows-7, grouping, taskbar

I wonder: Is there some way of programmatically preventing the Windows 7+ taskbar from grouping an application's icons on a taskbar when multiple instances get started? I am happy with the grouping as it is, except that in one specific application of my own design I would prefer ungroupped icons.

When I came across [SetCurrentProcessExplicitAppUserModelID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-setcurrentprocessexplicitappusermodelid), I was sure that was the answer - I would simply generate a new random string for each instance and that would get me a new taskbar icon. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work that way - even though I set a different AppUserModelID for each instance, they still get all groupped under the same taskbar icon. I would almost suspect that I got it wrong and AppUserModelID can only be used to group "unrelated" applications but not ungroup the related ones, but [this article](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/sasha/2009/02/15/windows-7-taskbar-application-id/) seems to indicate that my use case should work just fine.

About the only other cause of my problems which seems reasonable is the function's documentation's remark "This method must be called during an application's initial startup routine before the application presents any UI or makes any manipulation of its Jump Lists.", but as far as I can tell, I am adhering to the condition. Unless SetCurrentProcessExplicitAppUserModelID cannot be used with command-line applications because the taskbar icon gets created even before the application starts?

Comment: It's not the process you want to set the ID for but the window. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/shell/samples-appusermodelidwindowproperty

Comment: That would explain why my call is failing - at that time, I don't have a window yet. However, the text in the example seems to contradict the remark in the documentation: "Notice that [...] windows can change their identity at runtime." vs "This method must be called during an application's initial startup routine before the application presents any UI or makes any manipulation of its Jump Lists." Seems confusing.

Comment: Command-line applications don't have a GUI. You don't own the console HWND.

Comment: See [How do I customize how my application windows are grouped in the Taskbar?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20120820-00/?p=6813) on MSDN

Comment: @Remy Lebeau: That's pretty much what I am doing, without success. My guess the ownership of the console could play a role here. I will need to research a way of finding the real owner, then I will inject it with a remote thread that will call SetCurrentProcessExplicitAppUserModelID. Although, as far as I understand the whole concept, that would be too late because the taskbar icon already exists at that time.

Comment: there is a free app called "7+ Taskbar Tweaker" https://tweaker.ramensoftware.com/ that can do that